# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to print and get a row of numbers(2,4,8,16, 32, ) but then is should be greater than 10 but smaller than 1000 with LINQ expressions. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

The error occurs in my program.cs when i use from, it underlines r. I don't understand what this error means.

program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

 namespace _3._4
 {
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Reeks r = new Reeks();

      var query =
                     from i in r// error is here
                     where i > 10 && i < 1000
                     select 2 * i;

        foreach (int j in query)
        {

            Console.Write(j);


        }
    }
}
```

}

Reeks.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _3._4
 {
    class Reeks : IEnumerable
{
    private int i = 1;
    public Reeks() {  }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            i = i * 2;
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to implement `IEnumerable<int>` in `Reeks` as well as the non-generic version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq (i.e. the `from i in r` syntax you are using) requires you to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, not `IEnumerable`. So, as Lee pointed out, you can just implement `IEnumerable<int>` like this:

```
class Reeks : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int i = 1;
    public Reeks() {  }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            i = i * 2;
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

As a note, your enumerable returns an infinite list. As such, when you enumerate it, you need to terminate it manually using something like `Take()` or `TakeWhile()`.

Using `where` will NOT terminate the enumeration, since the .NET framework does not know that your enumerator only emits increasing values, so it will keep enumerating forever (or until you kill the process). You might try a query like this instead:

```
var query = r.Where(i => i > 10)
                      .TakeWhile(i => i < 1000)
                      .Select(i => 2 * i);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was really struggeling!